# How to make vertical scrollbar's height same as window's height and make horizontal scrollbar fixed?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure that I express myself in an understandable way.

So very similar to what I want to achieve is left-hand side scrollbar at [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/). Essentially, I want my vertical scrollbar to behave the same, and my horizontal scrollbar to be at the bottom of the page, but fixed (in W3C's example there's no horizontal scrollbar). Meaning that I can scroll the center page but left-hand side should stay put (i.e. it has its own scrollbars).

I managed to add scrollbars, and place some dummy text:

```
<div class="test">
  <p>folder-tree works!</p>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa //this works fine on x-axis
  bunch of:
   <br>
   sdasdsss
   <br>
   asdasdsss
</div
```

So both of my scrollbar are there, but still I have to scroll down (using browser's vertical scrollbar) more to see my-left-hand-side horizontal scrollbar.

[image]

[image]

Here is the CSS I've got so far:

```
.test{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    min-height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.test2{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

If anything means, I'm planning to display folder hierarchy within left-hand section.

**UPDATE**

As you can probably see from images, I'm using Angular. Here is a [repo](https://github.com/MiljanGitHub/Angular-Scrollbar) where you can pull the project. It is really simple project (student project). In `components` folder there are `dashboard` and `folder-tree` components with there simple `html` and `css` files. `.ts` are empty. So this is simple `html/css` problem. Once you start the server, just go to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Could you please adds a working snippet that presents the issue and the work you have made thus far? It will make answering this question simpler

Comment: I'm trying using jsfiddle, but it is displaying as I want actually to be :)

Comment: great! So it is working?

Comment: I wish, working correctly in jsfiddle, not in my code however

Comment: So it must be an environment issue if it works fine in one environment (jsfiddle) but not on your server. Can you please post the entirety of your code here and also the specs to your server where this does not work for me to investigate?

Comment: Hi Sean, I fell a sleep yesterday :)  Thank you for your willingness to help. I updated the original question.

Comment: Do not use min-height, but `.test{ height: 100vh; }`, or more accurate, lets say the header is 50px, then `.test{ height: calc( 100vh - 50px ); }`